# CSS 3 Card-Flip Animation error in chrome 19-21 for first animation

Tags: google-chrome, css, css-transitions

I am having a very weird problem. I do a css 3 cardflip animation for my portfolio. In Firefox everything works fine, but in chrome for some reason the first card has a wrong direction for the animation. As you can see, the left image shows the wrong animation, stretched wrong, while the right one is perfect. All the cards are created by a script so there can not be a difference in the html markup or the css for that matter.

Any Ideas? What kind of information can I provide to help figure this out?

Cheers Lukas

[image: Animation]

Comment: same also happen to me so I update my chrome browser there was some bug in many chrome version so I update my chrome and works fine...

Comment: I am running 21.0.1180.82, that should be fairly up to date, right?

Comment: ok I am using 23.0.1243.2 m.Hey can you give me link so I can test your css transition as I have similar css and it's working fine hope I can fix your issue

Comment: The site is not online at the moment, I am only testing locally. 23 is still like Alpha, right? Because I updated chrome (it had a bug) but it only went up to 21.....89.

Comment: ok...can you share the code so that I can test it on my chrome

Comment: Sure. Here you go, hope they fixed it and its just a bug. https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1839051/cards.zip

Comment: It work perfect and I tested in both browser and work same in both

Comment: What do you mean both? It works in chrome 21 for you too? Using a mac or pc? Can you post this as an answer, so I can highlight the post as answered? Awesome, anyway, this should solve my problem in a couple weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update

```
.card flip
     {
      text-decoration: none;
      text-align: center;
       float: left;
       position: relative;
       display: block;
       z-index: 30;
   }
```

Remove `perspective` and `webkit-perspective` they causing error

Comment: It does work, thanks. But there is a need to add perspective to another part.
```.card-flip .front, .screen .card-flip:hover .back{
 -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY( 0deg );
}```
AND 
```.card-flip .back {
 -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY( -180deg );
}```